# No visual clues as to hibernation status

Tags: 10.10, hibernate

When my laptop goes into or comes out of hibernation I'm presented with only a blank screen. Is there any way of providing a progress indicator for hibernation, similar to that of the boot screen for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install the uswsusp package, you will at least get a text progress indicator, and it will speed up the process.  I also might get around to fixing it to use a nice gui screen instead of text for Natty+1.